# After removeFromSuperview, first tableView cell hidden under NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that contains a button in the header that allows the user to post a Image. When the button is pressed, I create a postButton, cancelButton, and captionTextView programmatically -

```
UIButton *postButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 50)];
postButton.tag = 8934;
postButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[postButton setTitle:@"  Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addPicture.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50)];
cancelButton.tag = 8934;
cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then - `self.view addSubview:`. After the user presses the post or cancel button -

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (subview.tag == 8934 || subview.tag == 2387) 
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

The buttons and textViews are removed, BUT once they are removed, the `tableView` is shifted up and part of the first cell is hidden under the `naviagtionBar`

Comment: subview.tag == 2387 is your captionTextView I presume.

Comment: And this button in the header which creates the other buttons, hope that does not carry the same tag. Most importantly, are you using autolayout? Setting appropriate constraints and calling [self.view setneedslayout] whenever u add or remove subviews will fix this issue.

Comment: Yes 2387 is the tag. It is part of the header of the tableView that is hidden under the navigationBar and `[self.view setneedslayout]` did not work. @Vijayts

Comment: Could u share your autolayout constraints?

Comment: @Vijayts I fixed it. It was because I was hiding the navigationBar and tabBar when I created the new views then I called `hidden == false` after I removed the subviews. Now I call `hidden = false` before I remove the views and it works fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Me being stupid. Called navigationBar.hidden = false after I removed the subviews instead of before

Comment: Oh! A [self.view layoutIfNeeded] after that line would have still saved you,